# Save user input in to text file through batch file

Tags: batch-file, user-input

I have created this code and I cannot do so when I type some text to `username` and `yearsoflife` the text to be exported in a `.txt file`.

```bat
@echo off
color 0a
echo.
echo.
echo    Please insert the following
echo.
echo.
echo.
set /p username=name:
set /p yearsoflife=age:
%username% > name.txt
%yearsoflife% > yourage.txt
```

Comment: `(Echo=%username%)>"name.txt"`, `(Echo=%yearsoflife%)>"yourage.txt"`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I have realisted that i need them both in the same txt file any suggestions ?

Comment: Nevermind, i figured it out just had to put `(Echo=%username%,%yearsoflife%)>"file.txt"` , thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution:

```bat
@echo off
color 0a
echo.
echo.
echo    Please insert the following
echo.
echo.
echo.
set /p _username=name: 
set /p yearsoflife=age: 
(echo=%_username%) > name.txt
(echo=%yearsoflife%) > yourage.txt
```

You were not so clear in your question; you referenced that you want both variable contents in one textfile. So, for this you can try (double the `>` symbol):

```bat
@echo off
color 0a
echo.
echo.
echo    Please insert the following
echo.
echo.
echo.
set /p _username=name: 
set /p yearsoflife=age: 
(echo=%_username%) >> your_name.txt
(echo=%yearsoflife%) >> your_name.txt
```

*Note: Change of `set /p username=name:` line was just not to confuse this `username` variable with `username` environment variable!*